# Authentication Failure when trying to list shares in Azure Files service using PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, azure-storage, hmac

I am trying to authenticate to Azure Files Preview using PowerShell by hitting the REST API with Invoke-RestMethod. I am doing my best to follow the instructions provided here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx

This is my script:

```
$accountname = "testaccount"
$xmsdate = get-date
$xmsdate = $xmsdate.addhours(6)
$xmsdate = $xmsdate.toString('r')
$accesskey = 'lfksZQh0nasdfasd0KeMI+1alslv8ukK39Rsoelsldiq1r+zed9r4bH5uRyba+/QCwwvdGotw=='
$message = "GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:" + $xmsdate + "\nx-ms-version:2014-02-14\n/" + $accountname + "/ comp:list\nrestype:share\ntimeout:20"

$hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($accesskey)
$signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($message))
$signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("x-ms-version", '2014-02-14')
$headers.Add("x-ms-date", $xmsdate)
$headers.Add("Authorization", "SharedKey " + $accountname + ":" + $signature)
$uri = "http://" + $accountname + ".file.core.windows.net/?comp=list"
invoke-restmethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers
```

The error I get is "The MAC signature found in the HTTP request ... is not the same as any
computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'GET x-ms-date:Wed, 11 Feb 2015 23:25:06 GMT x-ms-version:2014-02-14 /testaccount/ comp:list"

I found the code which encrypts the message from here: https://gist.github.com/jokecamp/2c1a67b8f277797ecdb3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a few things I discovered:

- **Date/Time in UTC**

  $xmsdate = get-date
  $xmsdate = $xmsdate.addhours(6)
  $xmsdate = $xmsdate.toString('r')

Since the date/time must be in UTC, a better way to do it would be like this:

```
$xmsdate = get-date
$xmsdate = $xmsdate.ToUniversalTime()
$xmsdate = $xmsdate.toString('r')
```

- **"\n" causes problem**

Instead of using `\n` for new line character, use "$([char]10" or "`n" (https://twitter.com/gmantri/status/565694148637097984)

```
$newLine = $([char]10);
$message = "GET" + $newLine + $newLine + $newLine + $newLine + $newLine + $newLine + $newLine + $newLine + $newLine + $newLine + $newLine + $newLine + "x-ms-date:" + $xmsdate + $newLine + "x-ms-version:2014-02-14" + $newLine + "/" + $accountname + "/" + $newLine + "comp:list";
```

- **Use `Convert.FromBase64String` to convert account key into byte array**

  $hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256;

  $hmacsha.key = [Convert]::FromBase64String($accesskey);
- **Query string parameters must be the same in both URL and signature calculation**: In your case, you were including `timeout` parameter in signature calculation but it was not provided in the URL query string.

Based on these, please try the script below:

```
$accountname = "accountname"
$xmsdate = get-date
$xmsdate = $xmsdate.ToUniversalTime()
$xmsdate = $xmsdate.toString('r')
$accesskey = 'accountkey'
$newLine = $([char]10);
$message = "GET" + $newLine + $newLine + $newLine + $newLine + $newLine + $newLine + $newLine + $newLine + $newLine + $newLine + $newLine + $newLine + "x-ms-date:" + $xmsdate + $newLine + "x-ms-version:2014-02-14" + $newLine + "/" + $accountname + "/" + $newLine + "comp:list";
$hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha.key = [Convert]::FromBase64String($accesskey)
$signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($message))
$signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2014-02-14")
$headers.Add("x-ms-date", $xmsdate)
$headers.Add("Authorization", "SharedKey " + $accountname + ":" + $signature)
$uri = "http://" + $accountname + ".file.core.windows.net/?comp=list"
invoke-restmethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I wanted to stab my eyes out yesterday. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Newline character in PowerShell is `n and not \n. :)

```
$message = "GET`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`nx-ms-date:" + $xmsdate + "`nx-ms-version:2014-02-14`n/" + $accountname + "/ comp:list`nrestype:share`ntimeout:20"
```